# Cloudera fails to recognize hosts

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera, vsphere, esxi

Initially, i set up 2 machines (Ubuntu 12.04, x64) on vSphere server.

The name and ip of these two machines were

```
host                  ip
vm-cluster-node1      10.211.55.100
vm-cluster-node2      10.211.55.101
```

I have installed **cloudera manager in** `vm-cluster-node1`.

Then i cloned second one `(vm-cluster-node2)` to create 2 more hosts, and changed the ip and names as:

```
host                  ip
vm-cluster-node3      10.211.55.102
vm-cluster-node4      10.211.55.103
```

But the problem is, when i add these all 4 machines from cloudera, no matter how many times i try, i can only see two machines in **hosts** tab. later i realized that, if i refresh the web-page, i can see 2 machines only, but the second machine is switched between `vm-cluster-node2`, `vm-cluster-node3` and `vm-cluster-node4`.

to illustrate, i have included images to make things clear.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So, as far i've understood, the cloudera manager is not able to resolve the hosts cloned from same source as different machines. Even though the host-names and IPs have been changed. So is there anything that is common in these machines and this problem is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was that the three nodes/hosts have same `HOST ID`. This can be changed in `/etc/hosts/cloudera-scm-agent` file with `CMF_AGENT_ARGS="--host_id new_host_id"`